# Itinerary for a 12 Day Hiking Trip to South Island in New Zealand in December

Tags: air-travel, hiking, itineraries, new-zealand

I am currently planning a 12 day trip to the South Island of New Zealand from December 13th - December 24th. I am incredibly excited, but need need some help figuring out the right itinerary.

I will be traveling with a close friend. The two of us are males in our mid-20s, in good shape, and are hoping to take on one or two of the following Great Hikes:

- Heaphy Track
- Milford Track
- Routeburn Track
- Kepler Track

We are very flexible in terms of budget - and are very happy to pay a little more in order to save time. Most of our constraints are related to time. In particular, we need to:

- Fly into NZ on December 13th
- Rest and recover from jetlag for 1-2 days
- Fly out of NZ on December 24th

I'm wondering:

- Where should we fly in and out of in NZ?
- How can we get from these places to the hike?
- Can we fit in two of the great hikes?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please have a look at the [help] - as it stands, your question is  very likely to get closed.  For a start, you've asked at least 6 questions in one, which is usually frowned upon.  Also try to stay away from subjective questions or polling questions - "what would you do?", for example.  I'd suggest breaking them up into multiple questions.  Awesome area of my country that you're visiting though, and definitely the best island :)

Comment: For the hiking question, see [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: Best airport is probably CHC (Christchurch). Some carriers will take you to CHC directly but a greater number of flights go to AKL (Auckland). You can get internal flights from Auckland to Christchurch as a matter of course. Any travel agent will be able to book these for you along with your international flights. If you book the internal flights early you can get excellent rates AKL-CH. Je=t Star and Air NZ offer low cost "grab a seat" internal flights. 
You will be able to manage 2 trips if you plan carefully. Note that tracks may be booked out and you need to book asap.

Comment: Routeburn can be "walked" in 1, 2, 3, or 4 days (or run as a Marathon!!!). 3 is usual, 2 is not hard if fit. 1 is silly but people do it. My wife and I did it in 4 and enjoyed the scenery. Other tracks are the Greenstone and Hollyford. Hollyford is fairly long and further away from area most others are in. Milford is THE classic - most liable to be booked out. There is a (very) well developed industry serving transport to and from track ends and from Christchurch to and from the tracks. Any good NZ South Island travel agent will handle this regularly.

Comment: Where are you coming from? I doubt that you need the jetlag recovery time. If you allow 2 days from CHC to track end it should be enough if you have all your gear already. If you have more money than time then you can get light aircraft flights to locations near track ends.Even more $ gets you a helicopter :-). I can help with specific questions if you wish - see my profile for email address.

Comment: I live in Auckland. I'll be in Australia for 1st 2 weeks in November (Perth to Alice Springs) but may be on internet a limited amount. Or Skype address is RussellMcMahon. If they would un-hold this topic the above could be an answer :-).